# How to Open Embedded Object in Excel with Caption in Vba?

Tags: vba, excel

Try to open embedded object in excel file with caption,able to open file with name: can any one help how to open with caption or dynamically

```
Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
Set o = Worksheets(SheetName).OLEObjects("object 3")
o.Verb xlVerbOpen
MsgBox "Attachmene open"
```

Note: object will add continuously in excel file, how to find object dynamically to open with caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded object in Excel is a `Shape`. Add two embeded workbooks in your `ActiveSheet` and try this code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim obj As Object

    For Each obj In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print obj.Application.Caption
    Next obj

End Sub
```

Then try to change the code, with a simple condition, opening the `obj`, if the caption is the expected one:

`If obj.Application.Caption = "someCaption" Then OpenTheWorkbook(obj)`

At the end write some check to make sure that it skips some possible errors.

Comment: here caption is not expected one, title is expected one, and in my scenario all the excel object file will be attachment in excel workbook so caption property will have compulsory, i need to open object with caption or title

Comment: instead of "object 3" i want to open object with caption "book2" ,, my scenario, i cant check condition,because  object added by user, i need to find that added object caption and open the file dynamically,

Comment: So write the captions somewhere, and whenever a new one appears, open it, @stpdevi

Comment: @stpdevi - write the captions, then loop through all the shapes and check whether the caption of the shape is in the ones that you have written. If it is not, then it is something new, thus act accordingly.

Comment: nstead od Object 1, how to find title for embedded object

Comment: or can we rename "object 1" to "someother"

Answer (score 0):

I open an embedded WORD document through Excel using the following verb command.

```
Set o = .OLEObjects("Object 1")
  o.Verb xlVerbOpen
```

"Object 1" is the default name of the embedded object so that would be changed as needed.

Comment: instead od Object 1, how to find title?

Comment: If you click the embedded object, the title should show in the top left. Same spot where you would see "A2" if you clicked in that cell.